# Android : How to dismiss a dialog when an item is selected

Tags: java, android, modal-dialog

I found this library that implements the Material Design Dialogs, but the logic is defeating me somewhere. I want to dismiss the Dialog after an Item is selected.

**Adapter is Created as follows.**

```
MaterialSimpleListAdapter adapter = new MaterialSimpleListAdapter(new MaterialSimpleListAdapter.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onMaterialListItemSelected(int i, MaterialSimpleListItem item) {
        long id     = item.getId();
        switch ((int) id){
            case 10 : Email();
        }
        ////I have to dismiss the dialog here, but its created below.
    }
});
```

**Adding Item**

```
adapter.add(new MaterialSimpleListItem.Builder(this)
                .content("Send by Email")
                .icon(R.mipmap.ic_mail_gray_48dp)
                .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                .iconPaddingDp(8)
                .id(10)
                .build());
```

**And then the dialog is created from adapter.**

```
 MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .adapter(adapter, null)
                .autoDismiss(true)
                .show();
```

The problem is **MaterialDialog** is not yet created in the **onMaterialListItemSelected** since it depends on the adapter? How can I work this out?

Comment: You can put it on onMaterialListItemSelected() method .

Comment: please show the `onMaterialListItemSelected()` method.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you select an item, the dialog does not automatically dismiss (this should actually happen - since you specified `autoDismiss` - which is on/true by default).

Comment: @Himani that will require adapter to be final and we won't be able to add items

Comment: @BRG its the first code block on the question.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla that's what I thought when I put the AutoDismis, but its not dismissing.

Comment: implement method of doing dismiss dialog and call that method from adapter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes:

```
//declare as global the dialog variable
private MaterialDialog dialog;

final MaterialSimpleListAdapter adapter = new MaterialSimpleListAdapter(new MaterialSimpleListAdapter.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onMaterialListItemSelected(int index, MaterialSimpleListItem item) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //remove the autoDismiss(true) option, better use the Activity
        //context
        dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                .adapter(adapter, null)
                .show();
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This does it, tried it but had put dialog as a local variable which required it to be final. Guess I need to go study Java Scoping.

Comment: glad i could help!!

Answer (score 1):

Once the dialog is shown, you can dismiss it simply by

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: The problem isn't dismissing the dialog, but dismissing it in the correct context. Please reread the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

when you need to dismiss it.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem.